# Tensorflow seq2seq - confidence of reply

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bots, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to know if there is a way in Tensorflow's seq2seq framework where I can know if a reply to an input can be given with x% of confidence.

An example below:

I have `hi` as reply to `hello`. It works fine. I also have bunch of other trained sentences. However, let's say I enter some junk like this - `sdjshj sdjk oiqwe qw`. Seq2seq still tries to give a response. I understand it designed that way, but I want to know if there is a way which says the framework cannot answer this with confidence. Or no such words were trained.

This would be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use logistic function (or sigmoid) on the output logits:
Because logit function is basically the inverse of sigmoid function:

Logit Function:

[image: Logit Function graph]

Sigmoid Function:
[image: Sigmoid Function graph]

You can see that it is similar. In tensorflow. there is the sigmoid function, but I find the program is faster when you just code the sigmoid function:

[image: Sigmoid Function]

If you use sigmoid function. You will get a value from 0 to 1 which is the confidence you are looking for. More information can be found here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14577867)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, fixed it.

Comment: does this provide a confidence of the whole output, or just the last token? I guess @spiralarchitect wants it to reflect the confidence of the entire output.

Comment: So you basically put the entire logits to the sigmoid function. In this case, it will return confidence of all the classes (which you can set a threshold for). If you use the argmax function, then you will only get one highest value

Comment: However, one thing to understand is using sigmoid function, threshold for softmax loss  is like cheating. Because softmax loss will take into account the predictions of other labels to give out predictions. So that all confidence outputs add up to 100%. If you can, you should pick the output with the highest confidence.

Comment: @LongLe thanks for replying, but I am not sure I understood your point. My question is that for this particular model type (seq2seq) we have to output an entire sequence, based on an input sequence. And each token of that sequence is going to involve some sort of confidence, right? Then the question becomes, how to aggregate those scores into an aggregate score for the entire output sequence.

Comment: @mitchus Seq2seq model takes input as a sequence of string and outputs a "sequence of logits list". For each logit list in the sequence, seq2seq outputs the word with the highest logit one by one, using argmax function. If you want to aggregate score for entire ouput. Then a naive version would be to multiply all the confidences of all the tokens in the sequence. The problem is logit is not the same as probability. You need sigmoid function to convert logit (-inf to +inf) to probability (%).

Answer (score 0):

I think `average perplexity`returned by `seq2seq_model.model.stop` is the confidence, the smaller, the better. But it could be hard for one to tell a proper threshhold.

Comment: I think you mean `seq2seq_model.model.step`. I tried that. Its always 0.0 for trained and junk inputs. Maybe by corpus is less for it work properly? I have like 1000 training lines.

Comment: Check the greedy decoder in [translate.py](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py#236) on how it extracts the weights.

Comment: 1,000 lines is very small for training this type of model.

Comment: @AlexandruCeausu could be right. Seems like the perplexity only returned in training.